# simple factory (not autogenerated) in magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to create different models by condition.

```
if($fullActionName == 'catalog_product_view'){
    //get first custom model, 
} elseif($fullActionName == 'catalog_category_view'){
    //get second custom model
}
```

I find the correct way to do this:

1)

```
function __construct(FisrtModel $first, SecondModel $second){ ... }
```

But it's not sense add both model if only one will be use...

2)
Get personal model directly use object manager:

```
$this->_objectManager->create($modelName, $data);
```

But it's a bad practise..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
class MyFactory // feel free to rename it
{
    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
         array $map = []
    ) {
         $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
         $this->map = $map;
    };
    public function create($param) 
    {
         if (!isset($this->map[$param])) {
             throw new \Exception("There is no map value for {$param}"); //or you may just return null here
         }
         return $this->objectManager->create($this->map[$param]);
    }
}
```

then you need to add this in the `di.xml` of your module

```
<type name="MyFactory"> <!-- use here the class name as above -->
    <arguments>
        <argument name="map" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="catalog_product_view" xsi:type="string">First\Model\Name\Here</item>
            <item name="catalog_category_view" xsi:type="string">Second\Model\Name\Here</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Now you have to inject the class `MyFactory` in your class and just call

```
$this->factory->create($fullActionName);
```

if you choose to throw an exception in the factory, just wrap the code above in a try-catch block, if you choose to return null, just check if it returns null.

This way you make your factory extensible. You can later add a new full action name just by editing the `di.xml`. You can even hook into this from an other module using the `di.xml` by adding this:

```
<type name="MyFactory"> <!-- use here the class name as above -->
    <arguments>
        <argument name="map" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="checkout_cart_index" xsi:type="string">Third\Model\Name\Here</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good way is create CustomModelFactory with method `create($fullActionName)` and use objectManger to create right instance in it. Also will be good to check that created instance implements some interface and use it in annotation for method,
for example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/CatalogPriceFactory.php

Comment: Thank for your help!